# How can put multiple Hashmap in java into a new hashmap?

Tags: java

I have eight HashMaps in Java as follows:

```
     HashMap<String, Double> map1= new HashMap<String, Double>();
        HashMap<String, Double> map2= new HashMap<String, Double>();
        HashMap<String, Double> map3= new HashMap<String, Double>();
        HashMap<String, Double> map4= new HashMap<String, Double>();
        HashMap<String, Double> map5= new HashMap<String, Double>();
        HashMap<String, Double> map6= new HashMap<String, Double>();
        HashMap<String, Double> map7= new HashMap<String, Double>();
        HashMap<String, Double> map8= new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

I want to merge all in a new HashMap lets say NEW_MAP. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything before ? `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Double>> newMap= new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Actually I used the following code by it gives me duplicate key error in one of values    NEW_MAP  = Stream.of(map1, map2,map3,map4,
       map4,map5,map6,map7,map8).
          flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))

Comment: In this code the it is actually setting the keys in the final hashmap from the keys in the map that you have defined. i.e (if you have any duplicate keys in any of these map your code will fail).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am following your question correctly,there is a putAll() method in Map interface, you can merge them all to new HashMap by this method

eg :

```
Map<K,V> nhm = new HashMap<>();

nhm.putAll(map1);
...........
...........
nhm.putAll(map8);
```

Comment: i was trying to submit some code but everytime it said it was not properly formatted i could'nt figure out why, but i was using merge method of hashmap, you should study about how to use it.

Comment: yes, when there are cases of duplicate keys and you want to do some customization of values then merge method is more useful,dint understood your formatting issues though @The Goldy

Answer (score 1):

Then decide what to do with duplicate keys and use the third parameter of Collectors#tomap: (Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction))

```
Stream.of(map1, map2,map3,map4, map4,map5,map6,map7,map8)
      .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) 
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue
              )
      );
```

The above for example will keep the last seen value if duplicates are ditected. You can change it to whatever you want according to your requirements:

keep the first value seen: (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue

merge the two, e.g. by adding them: (oldValue, newValue) -> old + new

merge the two, e.g. by multiplying them: (oldValue, newValue) -> old * new

remove value: (oldValue, newValue) -> null

....

Answer (score 0):

You can combine usage of `putAll` from [RIPAN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60505895/11733759) and `Stream.of` from [Eritrean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60506597/11733759) for simple putAll:

```java
HashMap<String, Double> NEW_MAP= new HashMap<String, Double>();
Stream.of(map1, map2,map3,map4, map4,map5,map6,map7,map8)
.forEach(NEW_MAP::putAll);
```

But if you want some custom logic during merging duplicate keys, you can do as below (with choosing min value for example):

```
HashMap<String, Double> NEW_MAP= new HashMap<String, Double>();
Stream.of(map1, map2,map3,map4, map4,map5,map6,map7,map8)
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .forEach(e -> NEW_MAP.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(),
                (v1, v2) -> Math.min(v1, v2)
        ));
```

Comment: I tried your approach, however, it gives me "0" for all values. I mean the second one that merging with regards to duplicate keys.

Comment: I consider that it is about second approach. It depends on data that you have in your maps. Try for example instead of `(v1, v2) -> Math.min(v1, v2)` this  `(v1, v2) -> v1`. You should decide how you want merge duplicates.

Comment: @Hami Also I change code in second approach because It uses only two maps

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the second method and it worked for me.